# asp.net webapi form post lost data

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I post data to asp.net with form post.
    like

```html
   

<pre>
    <form method="post" url="apiurl">
    <input name="pwd" value="4QrcOUm6Wau+VuBX8g+IPg=="/>
    </form>`enter code here`
</pre>
```

but I got the pwd value is "4QrcOUm6Wau VuBX8g IPg==" on the server. The plus is lost!
    why?

Comment: May be it's taking as concatenation operator.

Comment: you can try UrlEncode and put the encoded value in a variable and then enter the variable name to the password field as value. This way you can preserve the plus sign I guess. Because adding "%2b" in the password would end up being mismatched with the encoded password you would compare it with during the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the plus signs to their URL-encoded counterparts, e.g.:

```
4QrcOUm6Wau%2bVuBX8g%2bIPg==
```

Plus signs are typically used in URLs to denote spaces, so that might be what is happening here.